# how to reference a result in a subquery

Tags: sqlite, subquery

I have the following table in an sqlite database

```
+----+-------------+-------+
| ID | Week Number | Count |
+----+-------------+-------+
|  1 |           1 |    31 |
|  2 |           2 |    16 |
|  3 |           3 |    73 |
|  4 |           4 |    59 |
|  5 |           5 |    44 |
|  6 |           6 |    73 |
+----+-------------+-------+
```

I want to get the following table out. Where I get this weeks sales as one column and then the next column will be last weeks sales.

```
+-------------+-----------+-----------+
| Week Number | This_Week | Last_Week |
+-------------+-----------+-----------+
|           1 |        31 | null      |
|           2 |        16 | 31        |
|           3 |        73 | 16        |
|           4 |        59 | 73        |
|           5 |        44 | 59        |
|           6 |        73 | 44        |
+-------------+-----------+-----------+
```

This is the select statement i was going to use:

```
select 
    id, week_number, count, 
    (select count from tempTable 
     where week_number = (week_number-1)) 
from 
    tempTable;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing values in two different rows. When you are just writing `week_number`, the database does not know which one you mean.

To refer to a column in a specific table, you have to prefix it with the table name: `tempTable.week_number`.

And if both tables have the same name, you have to rename at least one of them:

```
SELECT id,
       week_number,
       count AS This_Week,
       (SELECT count
        FROM tempTable AS T2
        WHERE T2.week_number = tempTable.week_number - 1
       ) AS Last_Week
FROM tempTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of you want to take a query upon a same table twice, you have to put aliases on the original one and its replicated one to differentiate them

```
select a.week_number,a.count this_week,
      (select b.count from tempTable b 
        where b.week_number=(a.week_number-1)) last_week
  from tempTable a;
```